# Amped Studio 2 - Sound Engine

Tags: javascript, audio, emscripten, webassembly

[This](https://madewithvuejs.com/amped-studio) website suggests, that [Amped Studio](https://ampedstudio.com/) uses a c++ sound engine compiled to wasm.

I am looking for **any** opinion, guess, assumption, what they might be using.

Generally, I am trying to understand the current situation of browser based DSP and the best sounding, low latency solutions for sound engines, APIs and libraries to build music related software on the web.

Any ressource would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last ADC [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORIpeFQqR9c) was given about porting the whole JUCE codebase (with some tweaks) to wasm https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORIpeFQqR9c

I recall the guy in the talk saying that he's involved with amped studio. This may be a starting point.

Even though I think JUCE is not a part of amped studio backbone, the stack should be not too distant from:

C++ (DSP engine + UI framework ) --> emscripten --> wasm & WebGL.

The engine could be anything really: from totally custom made to any existing open source C++ DSP thing properly tweaked to be portable to wasm.